# panoramio layer

Tags: google-maps, panoramio

Apologies if I have missed this in the API docs, but it is stated there that:

"The PanoramioLayer renders a layer of geotagged photo icons from Panoramio on the map as a series of large and small photo icons"

Is there any way to control this - i.e to show only small icons for instance?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to control this through the Google Maps API.